# Eclipse plugin install Error -- MD5 miss match

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have problem with my eclipse setup. I am not able to install any plugin via market place. I am behind company firewall and for internet connection we are using http proxy.

Following is the error that i am facing

```
!SESSION 2012-10-31 10:58:24.690 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.6.0_31
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product --clean
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product --clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2012-10-31 11:04:54.223
!MESSAGE An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2012-10-31 11:04:54.223
!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2012-10-31 11:04:54.223
!MESSAGE Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.zeroturnaround.eclipse,5.1.0.RELEASE-201210221548.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 1203 2012-10-31 11:04:54.223
!MESSAGE MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 4301b98a3bd7585b8f569a7576c541cd and found 2de8fa46c5bbe202ef4d1e67e1d7e1bd.
```

Thanks in advance for the help !!!